# Pinescript mark lower lows

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to mark lower lows. My idea is to use the built in `ta.pivotlow` function to identify the first swing low and then store that value in a variable `lastswinglow` (initialized with value `na`). Iterating from left to right, I will keep using `ta.pivotlow` and only update `lastswinglow` if it is lower or equal to the current value. So, plotting every `lastswinglow` value should mark all valid lower lows, but it's not working as expected - it seems like it is just marking every `ta.pivotlow`. Pinescript is below:

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="MS", title="Swing Points", overlay=true)

// inputs
swinglenl = input.int(1, minval=1, title="Consecutive candles to the left of swing point")
swinglenr = input.int(1, minval=1, title="Consecutive candles to the right of swing point")

// vars
float lastswinglow = na
pvtlow = ta.pivotlow(low, swinglenl, swinglenr)

if na(lastswinglow) or lastswinglow > pvtlow
    lastswinglow := pvtlow


plot(lastswinglow, style=plot.style_cross, color=color.red, linewidth=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `var` keyword so that your variable lastswinglow isn't reinitialized on every bar to na.

`var float lastswinglow = na`